# How to check whether graph of n vertex contains n/k disjoint k - complete graph by linear programming?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, linear-programming

Edges are given in form of $X_{ij}$, which denotes whether there is edge in between $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ vertex. I am solving integer optimization problem and want to add this constraint to it.

Comment: Do you mean *integer* linear programming, or just linear programming?  There is a significant difference.

Comment: Also, since you want the cliques to be disjoint, a more appropriate way to state the question is "how to check if a graph *is* $n/k$ disjoint $k$-cliques"

Comment: @amakelov: I assume the OP meant general subgraph, not induced subgraph, when asking about containment (otherwise the problem is completely trivial). If we allow general subgraphs, then a graph can certianly contain $n/k$ disjoint $k$-cliques but not be equal to $n/k$ disjoint $k$-cliques, just by adding some edges between the cliques...

Answer (score 1):

If you think of $1 - X_{uv}$ as the "distance" between $u$ and $v$, then you can impose the triangle inequality: $1 - X_{uw} \le 1 - X_{uv} + 1 - X_{vw}$, which can be rewritten $X_{uv} + X_{vw} - X_{uw} \le 1$. This forces (in integral 0-1 solutions) the vertices to group into cliques. You can then check that the degree of every vertex is $k-1$ to ensure they form $k$-cliques.